# Stationary distribution of a discrete markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $Y_n$ be a discrete markov chain with $Y_n=\{0,1,2, \dots \}$ and a  transition matrix 
$P=\left(
\begin{array}{c c c c c c c}
p_1+p_2+p_3 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
p_1+p_2 & p_3 & p_4& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
p_1 &p_2 & p_3 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
0 &p_1 &p_2 & p_3 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
0 & 0 & p_1 &p_2 & p_3 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
0 & 0 &  0 & p_1 &p_2 & p_3 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots \\
. & . &  . & . &. & . &. & . & .&.  &. \\
. & . &  . & . &. & . &. & . & .&.  &. \\
. & . &  . & . &. & . &. & . & .&.  &. \\
\end{array}
\right)$,

and let $p_1+p_2+p_3 + p_4=1$. We are searching for the Stationary distribution $\pi(x)$, so we have to solve the followin

$\pi(0)=(p_1+p_2+p_3)\cdot \pi(0) + (p_1+p_2)\cdot \pi(1) + p_1\cdot \pi(2)$

$\pi(1)=p_4\cdot \pi(0) + p_3\cdot \pi(1) + p_2\cdot \pi(2) + p_1\cdot \pi(3)$

$\cdots$

$\pi(k)=p_4\cdot \pi(k-1) + p_3\cdot \pi(k) + p_2\cdot \pi(k+1) + p_1\cdot \pi(k+2)$,for every $k=\{1,2,...\}$,

$1=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\pi(x)$

this can also lead to

$p_4\cdot\pi(0)= (p_1+p_2)\cdot \pi(1) + p_1\cdot \pi(2)$

$(1-p_1-p_2-p_4)\pi(k)=p_4\cdot \pi(k-1) + p_2\cdot \pi(k+1) + p_1\cdot \pi(k+2)$, for every $k>0,k \in \mathbb{N}$

$1=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\pi(x)$.

How can we solve this, I can't find a way to make a relation between different moments of the $\pi(k)$ in order to make something, I tried sum $(1-p_1-p_2-p_4)\pi(k)=p_4\cdot \pi(k-1) + p_2\cdot \pi(k+1) + p_1\cdot \pi(k+2)$, for every $k$, and use the fact that it is equal to 1, but it leads back to the first equation $\pi(0)=(p_1+p_2+p_3)\cdot \pi(0) + p_1\cdot \pi(1) + p_1\cdot \pi(2)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried it with numbers I think it's $\pi(n)=c\cdot p^n$ , for $n=0,1,...,$
  and $ p \in(0,1)$, you have to find $p$ by solving $\pi(k)=p_4\cdot \pi(k-1)\dots$, by replacing $\pi(k)=c\cdot p^k$ and keep the solution in (0,1). Then with $1=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \pi(k)$ find c.